# Else if statement works but seems confusing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand this answer (from JSHero) but I am confused so I have written the answer (which is correct) and written the explanation in step by step format.

**Original Question:**

Write a function addWithSurcharge that adds two amounts with surcharge. For each amount less than or equal to 10, the surcharge is 1. For each amount greater than 10 and less than or equal to 20, the surcharge is 2. For each amount greater than 20, the surcharge is 3.

Example: addWithSurcharge(10, 30) should return 44.

**Coded Answer:**

```
function addWithSurcharge (a,b) { 

let sum = a + b; 

if ( sum < 10) {
return sum += 2} 

else if (sum > 10 && sum <= 20) {
return sum += 2} 

else if (sum > 20 && sum < 30) { 
return sum += 3} 

else if (sum >= 30 && sum < 40) { 
return sum += 4} 

else if (sum > 40) {
return sum += 5} 
};
```

**Step by Step Explanation:**

> we declare a function addWithSurcharge

> it has two parameters

> we create if / else if / else statements to execute a block of code

> we declare a variable sum

> we initialize it with a value

> this value will be the sum of the two parameters which are numbers

> we use if else statements through out to check the total value of the sum

> if the sum of 2 digits is less than 10, then we can assume that both the digits are below 10
>
> > > > hence we can add a surcharge of 1 per digit which will make it 1+1 = 2

> if the sum of 2 digits is above 10, but less than or equal to 20, then we can safely assume that both the digits will be less than or equal to 10, but not above 10
>
> > > > hence we can again add a surcharge of 1 per digit which will make it 1+1 = 2

> if the sum of 2 digits is greater than 20, but less than 30, then we can safely assume that one digit will be less than or equal to 10, and the other digit will be less than or equal to 20
>
> > > > hence we can add a surcharge of 1 + 2 = 3

> if the sum of 2 digits is greater than or equal to 30, but is less than 40, then we can safely assume that one digit will be less than or equal to 10, and the other digit will be more than 20
>
> > > > hence we can add a surcharge of 1 + 3 = 4

> if the sum of 2 digits is greater than or equal to 30, but is less than 40, then we can also assume that both digits would be less than 20 or one digit could be less than 20 and the other could be equal to 20
>
> > > > hence we can add a surcharge of 2 + 2 = 4

> if the sum is greater than 40 then we can assume that one digit will be above 20, and the other digit will be equal to 20
>
> > > > hence we can add a surcharge of 3 + 2 = 5

> there is no else statement but we assume that in case both the digits are above 20 then the function will automatically add the surcharge for above 20
>
> > > > hence it will add a surcharge of 3 + 3 = 6

**My Specific Query:**

1. I am a bit confused with the statement: else if (sum > 40) { return sum += 5}. I understand that if the sum is above 40 then there is a good chance that both the digits are above 20 and hence the surcharge should be 6 instead of 5. I cannot understand this at all and am surprised as to how the code has passed the test.
2. I am also confused as to why is there no else statement in the end, and why do I need to assume that the else statement will automatically identify the numbers above 20 and add 6 as a surcharge.
3. Is there an easier way to code and understand this ?

Comment: what happens if sum is exactly 10?

Comment: what happens if sum is exactly 40?

Comment: What happens with the pair `(3, 13)`?  The code assumes that if the sum is less than `20`, each value is no more than `10`.

Comment: 1) Why would the surcharge be 6 when there is no 6 in any of your code? 2) Because you do not always need an else? Guess code assumes the number will always fall into one of those if/else if statements

Comment: 3) not sure how much easier a set of if statements can be made other than not including the lower check...

Comment: `if(sum<=10){} else if (sum<=20) {} else if (sum<=30) {} else if (sum<=40) {} else {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the code as provided is correct. It's trying to be clever but has forgotten to account for some edge cases in the assumptions it has made. I've collapsed and numbered the lines so we can take a look at it:

```js
function addWithSurcharge (a,b) { 

/*1*/    let sum = a + b; 
/*2*/    if ( sum < 10) return sum += 2;
/*3*/    else if (sum > 10 && sum <= 20) return sum += 2;
/*4*/    else if (sum > 20 && sum < 30) return sum += 3;
/*5*/    else if (sum >= 30 && sum < 40) return sum += 4;
/*6*/    else if (sum > 40) return sum += 5;

};
```

It looks like the primary motivation of this implementation is to reduce the number of comparisons that must be made. The problem statement clearly says that a surcharge should be added for each number that meets a specific criteria which means that we must check each number to see if it meets the criteria. This implementation attempts to get around that fact by deducing information from the sum of the numbers.

That might work if our numbers were more constrained. For example, if we knew that both numbers fell into the same range of ten, we could confidently say that their sum being less than twenty means they were each less than twenty. If the sum were less than twenty, then they each have to be less than ten since they fall in the same range.

The problem this implementation runs into is that the problem statement does not constrain the numbers in this way. It's not hard to imagine a case like `(3, 13)` where one number falls into the `<= 10` range and the other number falls into the `> 10, <= 20` range. The problem statement says we should add a surcharge of `1` for the first number and a surcharge of `2` for the second for a total surcharge of `3`, but this implementation only adds a surcharge of `2` because it assumes the sum being less than twenty means each number is less than ten.

> Line 1 sets `sum` to `3 + 13 = 16`, then line 3 adds a surcharge of `2` giving a total of `18` which is incorrect. `3` is less than or equal to ten so its surcharge should be `1`. `13` is greater than ten but less than or equal to twenty so its surcharge should be `2`. The total surcharge should be `3` for a total sum of `19`.

Just because the sum of two numbers is less than twenty does not mean that each of the numbers is less than ten unless that's a constraint that is not included in the prompt. Whether or not both numbers are less than ten is information that cannot be deduced solely by knowing their sum is less than twenty. There must be some other constraint or this implementation is incorrect.

---

As written (no subfunctions, no assumptions about the validity of the input, etc...), you can implement the function with two checks for each amount.

> Write a function `addWithSurcharge` that adds two amounts with surcharge. For each amount less than or equal to 10, the surcharge is 1. For each amount greater than 10 and less than or equal to 20, the surcharge is 2. For each amount greater than 20, the surcharge is 3.

```js
function addWithSurcharge(amount_a, amount_b) {

    let sum = amount_a + amount_b;

    if (amount_a <= 10) sum += 1;
    else if (amount_a <= 20) sum += 2;
    else sum += 3;

    if (amount_b <= 10) sum += 1;
    else if (amount_b <= 20) sum += 2;
    else sum += 3;

    return sum;
}
```

---

> Example: `addWithSurcharge(10, 30)` should return `44`.

1. Add `10` and `30` to get `sum = 40`.
2. `amount_a <= 10` so add a surcharge of `1` to get `sum = 41`.
3. `amount_b > 10` and `amount_b > 20` so add a surcharge of `3` to get `sum = 44`.
4. Return `44`.

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative answer. 

I was mainly interested in knowing the logic behind the answer that I have provided.

Could you please dumb it down for me if possible.

Comment: I've clarified why I think the implementation in your question is wrong. Its logic is assuming it can deduce some information about the magnitude of `a` and `b` from the size of their sum, but I believe I've shown the hole in that logic. The idea is good, but flawed.

Comment: Hey,

Hope all is well !!

To check for yourself, I'd urge you to visit this website:

JSHero.net

Check question 49 - else if exercise

You can check the code and see for yourself.

I am sure I have made some error in understanding this but you may also have a look at it yourself.

Let me know what you find.

Stay Safe !!

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly talking about a surcharge and your problem is correctly written then your example of:

```
Example: addWithSurcharge(10, 30) should return 44.
```

is incorrect. A surcharge is applied to the total of two or more items added together before discounts. That said in your example the correct answer would be 43 not 44.

However going off your examples:

```
function lineItemToSurcharge(a) {
  if ( a <= 10) {
    return 1
  } 

  if (a <= 20) {
    return 2
  } 

  return 3;
}

function addWithSurcharge (a,b) { 
  return a + b + lineItemToSurcharge(a) + lineItemToSurcharge(b); 
};
```

Break your problems down into smaller parts and they become way more simple.

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative answer. 

I was mainly interested in knowing the logic behind the answer that I have provided.

Could you please dumb it down for me if possible.